# What the sense of java frames?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, frame

I have found in docs for jstack:

> jstack prints Java stack traces of Java threads for a given Java process or core 
>        file  or a remote debug server. For each Java frame, the full class name, method name, 
>       'bci' (byte code index) and line number, if available, are printed. With the -m 
>       option, jstack prints both Java and native frames of all threads along with the 
>       'pc' (program counter). For each native frame, the closest native symbol to 'pc', 
>        if available, is printed. C++ mangled names are not demangled. To demangle C++ 
>       names, the output of this command may be piped to c++filt.

I know frame is element of visual interface, but in this context it seems different?
Search in Google produce links to visual element. It seems that frame is about threading. Does it possible found definition? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"frame" in this context refers to a [stack frame](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#17257), not a visual GUI element.

The short explanation is that every method call produces a stack frame, where local variables/results/return values are stored. By following the stack frames of your program, you can learn the current call stack

Answer (score 3):

Here "frame" means stack frame, the parts of a program's call stack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack